# How to pass a nested struct in Go

Tags: go, struct

A little 2 file application that reads a config file and stores it in a `struct`. How do pass **part of the config `struct`** to the `fetchTemperature` function?

**Configuration**

```
package configuration

type Config struct {
    Temperatures []struct {
        Temperature
    }
}

type Temperature struct {
    AppId string
}

func Load() Config {
    var c Config
    // -- 8< -- snip -- 8< --
    return c
}
```

**Main**

```
package main

import "configuration"

var c configuration.Config = configuration.Load()

func main() {
    for _, t := range c.Temperatures {
        fetchTemperature(t)
    }
}

func fetchTemperature(t configuration.Temperature) {
    // -- 8< -- snip -- 8< --
}
```

Gives me:

`cannot use t (type struct { configuration.Temperature }) as type configuration.Temperature in argument to fetchTemperature`

Isn't `t` of `configuration.Temperature` and if not, how do I pass the `struct` around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Config struct {
    Temperatures []struct {
        Temperature
    }
}
```

`t` is `Config.Temperatures[i]`. For `Temperature` from anonymous `struct { Temperature }`, write `t.Temperature` to select the field from the struct.

For example,

```
package main

import "configuration"

var c configuration.Config = configuration.Load()

func main() {
    for _, t := range c.Temperatures {
        fetchTemperature(t.Temperature)
    }
}

func fetchTemperature(t configuration.Temperature) {
    //  -- 8< -- snip -- 8< --
}
```

I suspect that your confusion arose because you wrote

```
type Config struct {
    Temperatures []struct {
        Temperature
    }
}
```

`Temperatures` is a slice of type anonymous `struct { configuration.Temperature }`.

What you probably wanted was

```
type Config struct {
    Temperatures []Temperature
}
```

`Temperatures` is a slice of type `configuration.Temperature`.

Comment: Thanks, that did work. Not sure why though. I understand why I can do `t.AppId`, but `t.Temperature` is not nested, `t` is a `Temperature`, or am I not getting that correctly?

Comment: @Cimm: See my revised answer for an explanation.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank as ton!